# Firestore getting the value from different documents

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

```
sportsRef.collection("sports").documents [
["bowling" : [
"equipment": "bowling ball, bowling alley, bowling shoes",
"description": "bowl the ball" ]]

["football": [
"equipment": "ball, boots, shin pads, goalie gloves",
"description": "kick the ball in the goal" ]]

["darts": [
"equipment": "darts, dartboard",
"description": "throw the dart at the board" ]]

["boxing": [
"equipment": "boxing gloves, ring",
"description": "punch your contender" ]]

["shot put": [
"equipment": "shot put",
"description": "throw the shot put, looks like a ball" ]]
]
```

```
db.collectionGroup("sports").whereField("description", [i don't know what to 
put]).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
@Override
   public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots){
//...
 }
});
```

Is there a possible way i can query all the value of the field "description"?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  What exactly does it mean to "query all the value of the field"? Have you read over the documentation for querying Firestore?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Sorry for the wrong use of words. I want to get all the values in the field "description".

Comment: Looks like you have just one value - a string?  What are you trying to do with it? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to store in an array these values : Bowl the ball, Kick the ball in the goal, Throw the dart at the board, punch your contender, throw the shot put, looks like a ball.

Comment: OK, what have you tried? Please edit your question to show your code and where you got stuck.

Comment: I dont know what to put inside the whereField function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query in Firestore limits what documents are retrieved from a collection. Since you want to retrieve all documents, you shouldn't be using a query.

```
db.collectionGroup("sports").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
@Override
   public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots){
//...
 }
});
```

Now this code will get all documents from all `sports` collections. Then in the `onSuccess` handler you can loop over these documents and get the `description` field from each of them.

There is no way to just get the `description` field from each document with the Android SDK. This SDK always retrieves complete documents, which is why you'll have to get the field in `onSuccess`.

If you don't want to transfer all the data for the other fields, consider creating a separate collection where you just store the `description` values of each document.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection("sports").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                            spinnerDataList.add(document.getString("Description"));
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
```